# Download a .zip file into a directory php

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question might have been asked before. I can't find what I'm looking for though so that's why I'm asking. What I'm trying to do is download a remote zip file from a remote URL.

I'm using Laravel 4 I tried the `Response::download($get->path, 200, array(content-type' => 'application/zip'));` but it just keeps saying `The file "http://remote.dev/new.zip" does not exist.` I also need to figure out how to move the .zip once it's downloaded to a new directory thanks for any help.

UPDATE: I solved it. I wrote up a full working example here http://tutsglobal.com/index.php?/topic/2-download-a-zip-file-into-a-directory-php/

Comment: It would be nice if you could write the solution below.

Comment: When I get some time Ill update this with the answer :)

Comment: Ok I wrote up a full working example of how I did it here :) http://tutsglobal.com/index.php?/topic/2-download-a-zip-file-into-a-directory-php/